# DNS wildcard entry from *.domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, seo

If a user enters ww2.domain.com he should be redirected to www.domain.com. This should be possible for all sort of subdomains (e.g. xxx.domain.com, ww.domain.com, ...). How should I set up the DNS record?

Will this DNS entry work?

```
*.domain.com.   CNAME (Type)    3600 (TTL)  www.domain.com.
```

**Solution:**

There were several steps involved for this. First I created DNS wildcard entries like this

`*.domain.com   A   3600    1.2.3.4`
`domain.com A   3600    1.2.3.4`

Than in the webhost settings I added a SEO redirect `*.domain.tld => www.domain.tld` with R=301,L. Furthermore for the alias domains the wildcard for the subdomains has been activated. Than I added in my `htaccess` the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.some-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work fine, however, I'd probably use an A record, rather than a CNAME record to save that extra lookup.

Also, bear in mind that this will *resolve* them to www.domain.com. but not redirect. So, for example, if a user starts accidentally using ww.example.com - they will be lead to believe that this is the correct web-address, which could cause issues further down the line. You will need to resolve this on your web server, though.

Comment: Rarely will there ever be an extra lookup within the domain itself. DNS servers make it their business to consolidate responses where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all subdomains to your www subdomain, you can set the A-Record for the wildcard(and the @ record, if you want the domain without any subdomain redirected, too).

But keep in mind you have to do the redirect on the server!